# Red5 deploy application

Tags: java, deployment, red5

i've a problem with deploying my application to remote server.

I've red5 server locally and i built an application here. But i want to deploy it to another remote server. I'm using Eclipse with red5 plugin, so there's no problem with deploying locally.

How can i deploy my application to another server?

I tried to copy application folder from webapps, but i have a conncetion error

```
NetConnection.Connect.Rejected: No scope 'myApp2' on this server.
NetConnection.Connect.Closed
```

Answer (score 0):

Before deploy red5 application to remote server You should [install red5 server](http://red5wiki.com/wiki/Installing_and_running_Red5).
After that you can write ant script that uses scp and sshexec ant tasks

Answer (score 0):

If the java version is not the same at the other server, you need to recompile your app. Make shure that your development server and your remote server use the same release of red5 and the same java version.

Have a look in your red5.log file to be shure that the app is starting proper.